# Help me with a 4S1P for vacuum cleaner please

Tags: batteries

I'm new here, and this is my first time trying to fix my Ilife V7S pro vacuum cleaner battery.

The original battery is this:

[image]

I want to replace the 4 18650 with my INR18650-25R daweikala
I have seen several videos of how to solder, risks of 18650 and other stuff, but after disassembly the pack (4S1P), i found this module, I'm not sure if it's a BMS or just a balancer or just a charger or a mix of everything.

This is the module:

[image]

As you can see, it has: V1, V2, V3, V4, P+, P- and B-

but I dont see B+

Could you please guide me how to make the connections? I see just one plug to discharge and to charge.

Thanks infinitely

---

Thanks Bruce. However I have another doubt. I included an image of what I understood the squematic is, but even after I joined all the wires, in the output of the module (P- and P+), i'm not getting the 14.8v only about 5v Do I have to connect the (-) and (+) (from the cells in serie that gives 14.8v) to the P- and P+? The terminals from the module P- and P+ should be 14.8. The one with thick wires i have from the battery in the image. BTW, is there a module that not only protects the batteries, but also balance the charge / discharge two in one. How should I look for it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: why don't you put it back together the way it was

Answer (score 1):

The module is a 'PCM' (Protection Circuit Module). It disconnects the battery if the voltage goes too high (overcharge) or too low (over-discharge), too much current is drawn (short circuit etc.), or the temperature goes too high. It does not do balancing or charging.

P+ and P- are the output terminals. B- is battery negative (negative terminal of lowest cell). Between B- and P- are a pair of MOSFETs which act as a switch to disconnect the battery when a fault is detected. V1, V2, V3 and V4 are the positive terminals of each cell (from lowest to highest voltage). V4 is connected to P+, so it has a thick wire to handle the battery current, while V1-3 are thinner because they only sense the cell voltages.

The circuit looks something like this (simplified):-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGWduP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To replace the cells you just have to unsolder the old ones and solder in the new ones. However there are two issues with DIY cell replacement:-

1. The cells *must* be balanced for equal voltage (within +-0.01 V) when fully charged. Since the PCM does not have balancing capability you must do this yourself. Easiest way is to fully charge each cell individually on a single cell charger, making sure the long-term resting voltages are the same. This makes connecting them up more dangerous due to the higher stored energy, so be careful! Keep all exposed terminals covered with insulation tape except for the one you are working on.
2. Cells are usually connected together with spot-welded nickel straps. If you don't have a spot welder then it is *possible* to solder wires to them, but unless you have vast experience at soldering battery packs there is a very high risk of damaging the cells and/or not getting a good connection (I *do* have vast experience, and even I avoid doing it if possible).

Due to these issues I don't recommend rebuilding the pack with individual cells. Send it to a professional rebuilder or buy a new battery.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. See the additional issue that I edited into the question.